# Objective-C - Mixing protocol and category

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In Swift, you could do something like this:

```
protocol Archivable: class {
}

extension UserDefaults: Archivable { }
```

Is there an equivalent in Objective-C to make NSUserDefaults conform to a protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in Objective-C

```
@protocol Archivable

- (void)doSomething;

@end

@interface NSUserDefaults (Test)<Archivable>

@end

@implementation NSUserDefaults (Test)

- (void)doSomething {
  NSLog(@"Do something");
}

@end
```

Try to use

```
[NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults doSomething];
```

Result

> Do something

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a new category of NSUserDefaults, and confirm your protocol and implement protocol methods in the category file.